# Вывод SMS по номеру отправителя

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, sms

Здравствуйте, знаю что в SDK есть методы для чтения каталогов смс сообщений. Подскажите как  получить список/массив входящих SMS с текстом и датой от определённого номера.
что бы выводились не все сообщения при нажатии кнопки, а только от одного определённого номера

```
   public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == btnInbox) {

        Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

        String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_str, c,
                new String[] { "body", "address" }, new int[] {
                R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber });
        lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Comment: Покажите ваши наработки. Справка по методам [тут](http://developer.android.com/) и [тут](http://google.co.uk/).

Comment: Делайте выборку из курсора по полю нужного вам номера. Примерно так:`String selection = "address="+number;` `Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, selection, null, null);`

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо огромное!